# How to ignore mv error?

Tags: makefile

I'm making a Makefile that moves an output file (`foo.o`) to a different directory (`baz`).

The output file moves as desired to the directory. However since make won't recompile the output file if I type `make` again, `mv` gets an error when it tries to move the non-existent empty file to the directory `baz`.

So this is what I have defined in my rule `make all` after all compilation:

```
-test -e "foo.o" || mv -f foo.o ../baz
```

Unfortunately, I'm still getting errors.

Comment: Look at what altendky did: -mv foo.o ../baz

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
+@[ -d $(dir $@) ] || mkdir -p $(dir $@)
```

is what I use to silently create a folder if it does not exist.  For your problem something like this should work

```
-@[ -e "foo.o" ] && mv -f foo.o ../baz
```

Comment: i still get an ignored error when using this but was the best solution so far. thanks

Comment: yes you will still get the silent ignore error from make, which I dont quite agree with as @ should make it completely silent.

Comment: @ does not affect the output from make of from the command, it only tells make not to print the invokation itself.

Answer (score 107):

[Errors in Recipes](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Errors.html) (from TFM)

> To ignore errors in a recipe line, write a `-` at the beginning of the
>   line's text (after the initial tab).

So the target would be something like:

```
moveit:
    -mv foo.o ../baz
```

Answer (score 62):

I notice nobody has actually answered the original question itself yet, specifically how to ignore errors (all the answers are currently concerned with only calling the command if it won't cause an error).

To actually ignore errors, you can simply do:

```
mv -f foo.o ../baz 2>/dev/null; true
```

This will redirect `stderr` output to `null`, and follow the command with `true` (which always returns `0`, causing make to believe the command succeeded regardless of what actually happened), allowing program flow to continue.

Comment: This is a good one. Of course someone could also drop the "true" part and use "-" if they wanted to see some output about the missing file.

Comment: I think the semicolon can also be replaced with `||` (or).

Comment: yes, if you want to increase your line length slightly :)

Comment: @Riot It also reduces the runtime by one execution in the case that `mv` succeeds.

Answer (score 2):

```
   -test -e "foo.o" || if [ -f foo.o ]; then mv -f foo.o ../baz; fi;
```

That should work

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
test -e "foo.o" && mv -f foo.o ../baz
```

should work: the operator should be `&&` instead of `||`.

You can experiment with this by trying these commands:

```
test -e testfile && echo "going to move the file"
test -e testfile || echo "going to move the file"
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and as I am generating files, they always have different time. Workaround is set the same time to the files: touch -d '1 June 2018 11:02' file. In that case, gzip generates the same output and same md5sum. In my scenario, I don't need the time for the files.