# Editing a makefile to allow debugging in linux

Tags: c, linux, debugging, makefile

I've downloaded a basic makefile which I'm trying to edit to allow debugging of the program in linux, however even after adding the -g flag to the makefile, the terminal just displays [ No Source available ] when running the gdbtui command instead of the debugging information as expected.

Here's the makefile in question:

```
CC=gcc
EXE=myprog

CFLAGS=
LDFLAGS=

OPTCFLAGS=-O2
DEBUGCFLAGS=-g

OBJ=main.o util.o

# Default Target, dependency on $(EXE) target
all: $(EXE)

# Optimised target, add OPTCFLAGS
opt: CFLAGS+=$(OPTCFLAGS)
opt: $(EXE)

# Debug target, add DEBUG Flags
debug: CFLAGS+=$(DEBUGCFLAGS)
debug: $(EXE)

$(EXE): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ 

%.o:%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

.PHONY: clean test
clean:
    rm *.o
    rm $(EXE)
```

Thanks for all the help in advance.

Comment: Did you *rebuild* the project? Just changing the flags will not cause make to rebuild the source since the files are not actually modified. Try `make clean; make debug` and see if it helps.

Comment: I tried 'make clean; make debug' however gdbtui still fails to do anything. Thanks anyway for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your makefile is OK for `make debug`.

`gdbtui` is reporting `[ No Source Available ]` right after you run `gdbtui myprog`
just because you have not yet started `gdb` so no debugging information
has yet been read from `myprog`

At this point you will see `gdbtui` prompting you:

```
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
```

Type `<return>`; then `gdb` still start; the source code will appear, and `gdb` will wait for
your debugging commands.

Apart from the oddness @MadScientist has noted about the default target,
there is this small bug in your makefile: The `clean` recipe:

```
clean:
    rm *.o
    rm $(EXE)
```

should be:

```
clean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f $(EXE)
```

or simply:

```
clean:
    rm -f *.o $(EXE)
```

Without the `-f` (`force`) option, if you were to delete the object files
without deleting `myprog` and then run `make clean`, it will fail at `rm *.o`
and not run `rm $(EXE)`.

Comment: ...Or even better, `-rm -f *.o $(EXE)`, because of [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Errors.html). See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143635/how-to-ignore-mv-error).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show the commands you're using to run make.  This makefile has the default target (`all`) not adding any flags at all (which is an odd decision).

In order to build an optimized version you have to run `make clean` followed by `make opt`.

To build a debug version of you have to run `make clean` followed by `make debug`.

What did you actually do?

Comment: I just ran 'make debug' to build the program, followed by gdbtui to debug it. Does the makefile itself need any changes to it, in order to succesfully run gdbtui ?

Comment: No.  Er... what command are you using to start `gdbtui`?  You _are_ giving it the command you want to debug, right, so `gdbtui myprog` ??  Also, you may have to page to get to the GDB prompt, depending on how big your terminal is; until you get to the prompt it won't show any source.